# Systemd customization

Tags: yocto, systemd

I have a minimal embedded system based on i.MX6 which doesn't have any network connectivity. I am planning to customize the systemd so that it will take less time to boot. Currently the user space is taking more time to boot. 
I have built images using yocto.

Is it possible to customize systemd using yocto? or need to disable the systemd services using sysctl once the board boots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done from yocto itself. But before getting into removal, make sure to list down the sub components/packages which you don't want in systemd.

Most of the time you may not be interested in timesyncd, timedated and other network related packages as well.

Get the complete list [here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_239.bb#n71). This is latest version of systemd bitbake with all the available packages it provides. Choose the list which you want and enable only the list which you want in .bbappend file

If you don't have enough control over the already enabled packages, create a custom .bbappend (may be in your custom layer) named as "**systemd_%.bbappend** and add,

**PACKAGECONFIG_remove = "list of packages to remove"**.

This will remove the packages which you don't want in systemd. The same procedure applies for non systemd components.

Comment: Thanks, added in the .bbappend file to remove unwanted packages and it worked. Is it possible to see all the variables and their values related to systemd recipe using bitbake?

Comment: @Ravi You can use devshell on your recipe if it supports. For example, `bitbake -c devshell systemd`. this will give shell with environments for the recipe. but not sure whether it will add the variables inside recipe to environment.

Comment: When I try to launch devshell, getting "Failed to execute child process "/tmp/tmpyw1cv1v2" (Permission denied)" error. Searched for this error but didn't get any info to fix, most of the explanations are related to giving execute permission to the file/script, but here the issue is related to the file creating at runtime under /tmp/. Using ubuntu 14.04 for building.

Comment: @Ravi: Am not sure about this. Probably something needs to be tuned in your system/environment. Usually `devshell` doesn't need any special permissions.

Comment: Initially got gnome terminal binary not found error, after searching in net add path for gnome-terminal. While copy pasting the line I have missed to add spcae +" ", due to this got permissiondenined issue. Now it is resolved, but not sure how missing space caused this permission issue.

Comment: Now tried to see the recipe variable values in the new terminal launched. Tried with env on the new terminal, but didn't see the systemd recipe variables( say depends ).

Answer (score 0):

First of all check how many systemd service files are running while boot up the board.
In `etc/systemd/system/` the path for all runnning services on boot up.
try to remove all services `(*.services`) one by one and boot the board.

Comment: I was removing services one by one, but when I remove few services like `mountnfs.service, dmesg.service` then time was increased by 1sec. Checking the time using systemd-analyze. The services `dev-mmcblk1p2.device (8.571s), systemd-logind.service (1.718s), console-kit-log-system-start.service (1.075s), rc-local.service (1.022s), systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service (915ms), psplash-quit.service (553ms)` are taking significant time.
Not sure about `dev-mmcblk1p2.device` service, is it parent for all services?

Comment: I have tried to chnage the default target to basic.target using `systemctl set-default basic.target`. But after booting the board login prompt is not coming. No update after `Started Console System Startup Logging` on the console.

Comment: @Ravi. first learn systemd and start working. "mountnfs.service" this srvice will mount your roots if u remove this you rootfs get affected to mount.

Comment: From the name I thought it is related to NFS mounting so I disabled it, after disabling it board is booting completely and login prompt is coming, my guess is may be the other services which depend on "mountnfs.service" are retried due to which time to boot is increased to 1 more sec. Can you guide to understand why login prompt is not getting with basic.target.

Comment: I have changed the default target to basic `systemctl set-default basic.target`, after the this change rebooted the board, now not getting the login prompt. The login service is at `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service` and the binary is at `/lib/systemd/systemd-logind`. How to modify the basic.target to start login service. Is it possible to skip login serveice and get command prompt directly.